# How to use type (typescript type) in swagger @ApiProperty type

Tags: javascript, typescript, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm facing a problem.
I need to expose a 'type' in an @ApiProperty of swagger on my API.
But swagger don't accept it. I looked in many website to find solution but I did not find any.

Here is the error I get:

> TS2693: 'testTest' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value
> here.

```
type testTest = 'A' | 'B';

    @ApiProperty({
  type: testTest,
  example: 'fr',
})
test: testTest;
```

I can't use something else since the type I need to use is from an external library.

Comment: You can't. Swagger needs a _value_, the types are all erased in compilation.

Comment: Sure, you totally right. But: how can I convert a type to an array of values of the keys of the type ?

Comment: you can't. Also that type would be an `string`. So `type: String`. And you will need to set up some sort of validation to ensure that `test` is either `'A'` or `'B'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a TypeScript `type` as a value for `type` in Swagger because `type` you are importing from the said library is not available at runtime, or once its transpiled to javascript. its only used for type checking. Thats how typescript works. This is same for any type, interfaces, return types etc...

What I suggest you do is to have a variable hold the values in `type testTest = 'A' | 'B';`

```
const testTest = ['A','B'];

@ApiProperty({
  type: String,
  example: testTest[0],
  enum: testTest
})
test: testTest;
```